# Menú deslizable con boton (overflow)

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, flexbox

Saludos estoy creando un menú, pero es muy largo, para solucionar esto estoy utilizando la propiedad css overflow:scroll.

Ahora quisiera hacer un botón que al darle click se desplace a la derecha para ver el resto de menú y no usar la barra de scroll

Modificado para que se entienda mejor: Este es un codigo de ejemplo (el width:120% es solo para hacer ver el scroll)

```
    .dropdown {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        padding: 16px;
        font-size: 16px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 120%;
        overflow: scroll;

    }
    a {
        padding: 10px;
        
        
    }


<div class="dropdown">
      <a href="#">Link largo 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link largo 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link largo 3</a>
      <a href="#">Link mas largo 4</a>
      <a href="#">Link mas largo 5</a>
      <a href="#">Link mas largo 6</a>
      <a href="#">Link mas largo 7</a>
      <a href="#">Link mas largo 8</a>
      <a href="#">Link mas largo 9</a>
      <a href="#">Link largo 10</a>
      <a href="#">Link largo 11</a>
      <a href="#">Link largo 12</a>
      <a href="#">Link largo 13</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Necesito colocar una fecha o boton a partir del Link 7 que mueva automaticamente el Scroll horizontalmente mostrandome el resto del menu

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo quieres crear un menu con dropdown

HTML

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero no es lo que necesito, seguro me explique mal, no coloco el codigo porque no tiene mucho sentido pero te hago un ejemplo:

Tengo un menu Horizontal que esta compuesto por 12 Items:

Menu1 | Menu2 | Menu 3 | ........... Menu12

ahora en pantalla con el responsive muestro 8 Items y puse un overflow-x para hacer scroll horizontal hasta alli funciona todo perfecto..

Lo que quiero hacer es que al lado del item8 aparezca un boton (>) para poder mostrar el resto del menu que no se ve y no tener que hacer scroll horizontal que es mas complicado para el usuario

Comment: Por eso te recomendé el dropdown, pero activalo mediante el tamaño del menú. Usando el tamaño del menú y de cada ítem del menú calculas cuando debe ser agregado al dropdown y mostrarlo sólo cuando sea necesario

Comment: cada item del menu uso megamenu, no puedo usar dropdown

Comment: Por eso se pide codigo, sabiendo eso te hubiera dado otra respuesta xD, en ese caso podrías simplemente crear una flecha que mueva el menú así tipo carousel

Comment: ya modifique la pregunta, quizas asi se entiende un poco mas y de nuevo gracias